# insert one column data from a table into other table, but the other column data will be specified dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i have 2 tables.
TABLE A COLUMNS - aid , aname
TABLE B COLUMNS - bid , bname

from table A, i will pick up data from column 'aid', 
AND insert it in **'bid'** column of table B , but in  **bname** column of table B, i will insert a new value. how do i do this?

```
create table A(aid int,aname char)

insert into A values(111, 'e') 


create table B(bid int, bname char)


insert into B (bid,bname)
```

bid will take value from the query : select aid from a 
bname will get a new value -m

expected result should be : THE TABLE B  WILL HAVE :

bid    bname
---    -----
111    m

Comment: And what do you want to insert on `bname`?, what is the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into b (bid, bname) select aid, 'm' as bname_fixed_val from a
```

Two facts enabled the solution above:

1. The `insert .. select` clause allows you to insert the values returned with any `select`.
2. You can return constant values as fields with `select`, like for instance:

   ```
   SELECT 0 as id, 'John' as name
   ```

Combining these two points together, I used an `insert..select` clause to select the field value from the first table (`aid`), along with a constant value for the second field (`m`). The `AS bname_fixed_val` clause is simply a field alias, and can be omitted.

For more information on SQL, here 's a link: http://www8.silversand.net/techdoc/teachsql/index.htm, although googling it wouldn't hurt also.

Comment: thanks a lot sir, it worked , can i have a simple explanation also on this query , which you advised