# asp SQL Statement to insert multiple rows of record into Table

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, insert, rows

I am trying to create an attendance table to record down the activities the students have participated. The code below is triggered when a new activity is created. When a new activity is created, I want to insert all the student record into attendance table and mark the default attend attribute as false. (the attend attribute is to mark attendance, sets as 0)

The problem is that the attendance table cannot be populated. The code will stop proceeding at the line: numofRecordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

I am trying to get the all the sigstudentid(s) from the Student table. I do not know if the usage of foreach() is recommended in this case, but any help will be appreciated.

I need a solution!

```
    public int InsertAttendance(int num)
        {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection();
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        String sqlText = "SELECT * FROM Student";
        connect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=TECKISTTLE; Initial Catalog=Assignment;    Integrated Security=True";
        command.Connection = connect;
        command.CommandText = sqlText;

        int numofRecordsAffected = 0;

        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        connect.Open();
        adapter.Fill(dataset, "StudentData");
        sqlText = "";

        foreach (DataRow item in dataset.Tables["StudentData"].Rows)
        {
            sqlText += " INSERT INTO Attendance(SIGStudentID, ActivityId, Attendance) VALUES(@SIGStudentID,@ActivityId,@Attendance); ";
            command.Parameters.Clear();
            command.Parameters.Add("@SIGStudentID", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters["@SIGStudentID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(item["SIGStudentID"]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@ActivityId", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters["@ActivityId"].Value = num;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Attendance", SqlDbType.Bit);
            command.Parameters["@Attendance"].Value = 0;



        }
        numofRecordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connect.Close();

        return numofRecordsAffected;
    }
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you are using ??

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio 2012

Comment: That's **NOT** ASP Classic (that would be VBA code only) - I assume you mean `asp.net` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you put the code `numofRecordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();` out side your `foreach`.
It just execute one time. As this code is actual statement to `INSERT` data in to the table, it will `INSERT` only one `ROW` the last one.

Just try to put your code

`numofRecordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

inside the `foreach` block. Then  it will `INSERT` each row.

```
    public int InsertAttendance(int num)
    {
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection();
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    String sqlText = "SELECT * FROM Student";
    connect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=TECKISTTLE; Initial Catalog=Assignment;    Integrated Security=True";
    command.Connection = connect;
    command.CommandText = sqlText;

    int numofRecordsAffected = 0;

    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    connect.Open();
    adapter.Fill(dataset, "StudentData");
    sqlText = "";
    numofRecordsAffected = 0;
    sqlText = "INSERT INTO Attendance(SIGStudentID, ActivityId, Attendance) VALUES(@SIGStudentID,@ActivityId,@Attendance); ";
    command.CommandText = sqlText;
    foreach (DataRow item in dataset.Tables["StudentData"].Rows)
    {
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SIGStudentID", Convert.ToInt32(item["SIGStudentID"]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivityId", num);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attendance", 0);

        numofRecordsAffected += command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }


    connect.Close();

    return numofRecordsAffected;
}
```

Comment: The Attendance table could not receive any record from the code above. Is there any thing I should take note of?

Comment: I have modified your code in my answer, see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, Accept my answer and vote up to show your appreciation.

Comment: Requires 15 reputation. I'll build up

Comment: ok, but as this is your question, you can accept the answer even if you don't have reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably over complicating it a bit by using a loop and could do something like this instead:

```
"INSERT INTO Attendance(SIGStudentID, ActivityId, Attendance) select SIGStudentID, " + num + " as ActivityId, 0 as Attendance from Student;"
```

Reference:

[insert one column data from a table into other table, but the other column data will be specified dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196116/insert-one-column-data-from-a-table-into-other-table-but-the-other-column-data)

[Insert all values of a table into another table in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576441/insert-all-values-of-a-table-into-another-table-in-sql)